# Diag Function to create a matrix

Tags: matrix, diagonal

How would I go about creating the matrix

```
[1  2  0  0  0;
-1  1  2  0  0;
 0 -1  1  2  0;
 0  0 -1  1  2;
 0  0  0 -1  1]
```

using the diag command in MatLab?

Comment: Why would you want to do that, I wonder ?

Comment: It is part of an exercise to familiarise myself with MatLab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
> diag(ones(1,5),0)+diag(ones(1,4),1)*2+diag(ones(1,4),-1)*-1
ans =

   1   2   0   0   0
  -1   1   2   0   0
   0  -1   1   2   0
   0   0  -1   1   2
   0   0   0  -1   1

>
```

This just creates three diagonals at 0, +1 and -1, scales them as needed, then adds them.